# Sort array of objects by subarray property value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, sub-array

I have an array of JavaScript objects:

```
var people = [
{
    "name": "Edward",
    "age": 100,
    "wallet": {
        "location": "home",
        "cash": 500
    },
    "bank": {
        "location": "bank street",
        "cash": 22100
    }
},
{
    "name": "Lisa",
    "age": 30,
    "wallet": {
        "location": "home",
        "cash": 20
    },
    "bank": {
        "location": "bank street",
        "cash": 12340
    }
},
{
    "name": "Elisabeth",
    "age": 50,
    "wallet": {
        "location": "home",
        "cash": 200
    },
    "bank": {
        "location": "bank street",
        "cash": 5000
    }
}
];
```

How can I sort them by wallet.cash ?

This following example (by Ege Özcan) works if I wanted to sort these objects by name, or age, but I have hard time modifying it to work with multidimensional key.

```
function dynamicSort(property) {
var sortOrder = 1;
if(property[0] === "-") {
    sortOrder = -1;
    property = property.substr(1);
}
return function (a,b) {
    var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
    return result * sortOrder;
}
}
```

This works:

```
people.sort(dynamicSort("name"));
```

This doesn't:

```
people.sort(dynamicSort("wallet.cash"));
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass two different arguments to dynamicSort function

```
function dynamicSort(property1,property2) {
var sortOrder = 1;
if(property1[0] === "-") {
    sortOrder = -1;
    property1 = property1.substr(1);
}
return function (a,b) {
    var result = (a[property1][property2] < b[property1][property2]) ? -1 : (a[property1][property2] > b[property1][property2]) ? 1 : 0;
    return result * sortOrder;
}
}
```

And then call

```
dynamicSort("wallet","cash");
```

**DEMO**

```js
var people = [
{
    "name": "Edward",
    "age": 100,
    "wallet": {
        "location": "home",
        "cash": 500
    },
    "bank": {
        "location": "bank street",
        "cash": 22100
    }
},
{
    "name": "Lisa",
    "age": 30,
    "wallet": {
        "location": "home",
        "cash": 20
    },
    "bank": {
        "location": "bank street",
        "cash": 12340
    }
},
{
    "name": "Elisabeth",
    "age": 50,
    "wallet": {
        "location": "home",
        "cash": 200
    },
    "bank": {
        "location": "bank street",
        "cash": 5000
    }
}
];

    function dynamicSort(property1,property2) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(property1[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property1 = property1.substr(1);
    }
    return function (a,b) {
        var result = (a[property1][property2] < b[property1][property2]) ? -1 : (a[property1][property2] > b[property1][property2]) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
    }

alert(JSON.stringify(people.sort(dynamicSort("wallet","cash"))))
```

Comment: Thanks man! This was exactly what I was looking for.
The first code part however is missing property -> property1 changes.

Answer (score 0):

Lifting this comparison function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript), you can do:

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.wallet.cash < b.wallet.cash)
    return -1;
  if (a.wallet.cash > b.wallet.cash)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

var people = [...];
console.log(people.sort(compare));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.byString` method from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621/696395) and modify your code like this:

```
function dynamicSort(property) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(property[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property = property.substr(1);
    }
    return function (a,b) {
        var avalue = Object.byString(a, property);
        var bvalue = Object.byString(b, property);
        var result = (avalue < bvalue) ? -1 : (avalue > bvalue) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}
```